# JCL Sort for VB file

Tags: sorting, dfsort

I Have 50 bytes of VB file

```
EMP Name    Pic X(5)
EMP ID      S9(9) comp
EMP Address Pic X(3)
```

we need to sort the file based on EMP address by ascending order
so where the record position will start?

SORT FIELDS=(20,3,CH,A)

Is this correct ?

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer, if it was what you needed?

Answer (score 2):

No, not corrcect.

The "PIC X(5)" is 5 bytes in length, the "PIC S9(9) COMP is 4 bytes, so the "EMP Address" starts at byte 10 of the data. Since the record format is VB, the first data byte comes *after* the RDW (4 bytes). Therefore:

`SORT FIELDS=(14,3,CH,A)`

Comment: Good. Then please mark the answer as accepted.